Classification of real polynomial vector fields on R2, up to polynomial automorphisms?
A result of Brunella classifies complete complex polynomial vector fields on ${\mathbb C}^2$, up to polynomial automorphism, and relies heavily on an earlier work of Suzuki.  I haven't fully digested this classification -- there are three types of complex vector fields, and the third is mysterious to me.  But still it is kind of remarkable to me that such a classification is possible.
My question is whether there is a similar classification for real polynomial vector fields on ${\mathbb R}^2$, up to real polynomial automorphism.  In other words, I want to look at vector fields $P(x,y) \cdot \partial / \partial x + Q(x,y) \cdot \partial / \partial y$ with $P,Q \in {\mathbb R}[x,y]$, modulo equivalence given by polynomial automorphisms $(x,y) \mapsto (F(x,y), G(x,y))$ with $F,G \in {\mathbb R}[x,y]$.

Is such a result proven or "known"?  In general or under some hypotheses (Brunella requires completeness).
Is such a result expected or conjectured?

One might attempt a sort of reduction for vector fields, using the elementary automorphisms as identified by Friedland and Milnor... but I haven't experimented along these lines yet.
Brunella, Marco, Complete polynomial vector fields on the complex plane., Topology 43, No. 2, 433-445 (2004). ZBL1047.32015.
Suzuki, Masakazu, Sur les opérations holomorphes du groupe additif complexe sur l’espace de deux variables complexes, Ann. Sci. Éc. Norm. Supér. (4) 10, 517-546 (1977). ZBL0403.32020.
Friedland, Shmuel; Milnor, John, Dynamical properties of plane polynomial automorphisms, Ergodic Theory Dyn. Syst. 9, No. 1, 67-99 (1989). ZBL0651.58027.
